# UITableView - set up tableview with Hpple data

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml, uitableview

I get some data from an xml file on the web using hpple. In my xml file I have a bunch of different sections that I get data from (About 20).

Heres the code I am using to get the data

```
- (void)getMenuItems:(NSString*)url{

NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
    //NSLog(@"response == %@", response);

    [self getDeli:data];
}

- (void)getDeli:(NSData*)deliData {
TFHpple *Parser = [TFHpple hppleWithHTMLData:deliData];
// 3
NSString *XpathQueryString = self.deliString;

NSArray *Nodes = [Parser searchWithXPathQuery:XpathQueryString];

// 4
NSMutableArray *newNodes = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];
for (TFHppleElement *element in Nodes) {
    // 5
    Items *item = [[Items alloc] init];
    [newNodes addObject:item];

    // 6
    item.title = [[element firstChild] content];
    item.title = [[[element firstChild] content]stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""];


    // 7
    item.url = [element objectForKey:@"href"];
}

// 8
_deli = newNodes;
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

}

The code all works, and I get the data the problem is that not all the sections all have data, and setting the titles of the sections and setting the data in the CellForRowAtIndexPath is a hassle as I change it depeing on what is returned and same with the number of sections.

So I looking to find out how much sections are returned how, and set that to the number of sections in tableview and then set the section headers to the title in the xml file section headers and such.

So that I don't just set the header and row height to 0 if the section or cell is empty.

I hope that makes sense...

Here is most of xml file

```
<day name="monday">
<meal name="DINNER">
<counter name="Chefs Choice">
<dish>
<name>Vegetable Samosa with Yogurt Sauce</name>
</dish>
<dish>
<name>Tomato Red Pepper Chutney</name>
</dish>
<dish>
<name>Curried Rice & Lentils</name>
</dish>
</counter>
<counter name="Entrée">
<dish>
<name>London Broil</name>
</dish>
<dish>
<name>Oven Roast Rosemary Red Potatoes</name>
</dish>
<dish>
<name>Glazed Fresh Carrots</name>
</dish>
<dish>
<name>Salad Bar</name>
</dish>
<dish>
<name>Cheddar Cheese & Bacon Potato Salad</name>
</dish>
</counter>
<counter name="Grill">
<dish>
<name>Hamburger</name>
</dish>
<dish>
<name>Classic Cheeseburger on a Toasted Bun</name>
</dish>
<dish>
<name>Chicken Sandwich</name>
</dish>
<dish>
<name>French Fries</name>
</dish>
</counter>
<counter name="International">
<dish>
<name>Shell Pasta</name>
</dish>
<dish>
<name>Spaghetti Sauce with Tomato Bits</name>
</dish>
<dish>
<name>Alfredo Sauce</name>
</dish>
</counter>
<counter name="Pizza">
<dish>
<name>Cheese Pizza</name>
</dish>
<dish>
<name>Pepperoni Pizza</name>
</dish>
<dish>
<name>Antipasto Pizza Slice</name>
</dish>
</counter>
<counter name="Soup">
<dish>
<name>Tomato Soup Florentine</name>
</dish>
</counter>
<counter name="Vegetable">
<dish>
<name>Eggplant Parmesan Casserole</name>
</dish>
</counter>
</meal>
</day>
```

Thanks for the help in advance

Comment: It is hard to tell from the code you have posted, but it seems that you are just storing everything into an array.  You probably need to create a more sophisticated data model class and parse the data into that - for example, an dictionary that contains an array for each section. The key would be the section name and then you can exclude sections where the array count is 0

Comment: @Paulw11 ya that sounds along the lines of what I was thinking just not quite sure where to start

Comment: What is your XPathQueryString or deliString?  ie. which nodes are you processing in the for loop?

Comment: sorry about that `deliString = @"//day[@name='monday']/meal[@name='LUNCH']/counter[@name='Deli']/dish/name";`

Comment: @Paulw11 hey http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63452/paulw11 can you join chat? Im trying to figure this out but I can't figure out to set up the dictionary

Comment: @Paulw11 just wondering if you had seem message about setting up to get data from web

Comment: @Paulw11 I added a question to chat

Comment: @Paulw11 one last thing in chat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to parse the XML structure into an appropriate data model object so that you can access the data via a hierarchy.

This is a data model class that could work -

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, DeliDay) {
    DeliDayMonday=0,
    DeliDayTuesday=1,
    DeliDayWednesday=2,
    DeliDayThursday=3,
    DeliDayFriday=4,
    DeliDaySaturday=5,
    DeliDaySunday=6,
    DeliDayUnknown=-1
};


@interface DeliData : NSObject


@property (strong,nonatomic,readonly) NSArray *days;
@property (strong,nonatomic,readonly) NSArray *meals;
@property (strong,nonatomic,readonly) NSArray *counters;


-(id)init:(NSData *)menuData;

-(NSArray *) itemsForMeal:(NSString *)meal onDay:(DeliDay)day atCounter:(NSString *)counter ;
-(NSArray *) mealsForDay:(DeliDay)day;
-(NSArray *) countersForMeal:(NSString *)meal onDay:(DeliDay)day;

+(DeliDay)deliDayForString:(NSString *)dayString;
+(NSString *)stringForDeliDay:(DeliDay)day;

@end
```

The parse method needs to work through the tags and build the data structures -

```
-(void)parseXML:(NSData *)menuData {
    TFHpple *Parser = [TFHpple hppleWithXMLData:menuData];
    NSString *XpathQueryString = @"//day";

    NSArray *Nodes = [Parser searchWithXPathQuery:XpathQueryString];

    for (TFHppleElement *element in Nodes) {

        NSString *dayString=element.attributes[@"name"];

        DeliDay day=[DeliData deliDayForString:dayString];

        if (day != DeliDayUnknown) {
            NSMutableDictionary *dayDict=(NSMutableDictionary *)self.menuData[day];
            NSArray *mealsArray=[element childrenWithTagName:@"meal"];
            for (TFHppleElement *mealElement in mealsArray) {
                NSString *mealName=mealElement.attributes[@"name"];
                NSMutableDictionary *counterDict=(NSMutableDictionary *)dayDict[mealName];
                if (counterDict == nil) {
                    counterDict=[NSMutableDictionary new];
                    dayDict[mealName]=counterDict;
                }
                NSArray *countersArray=[mealElement childrenWithTagName:@"counter"];
                for (TFHppleElement *counterElement in countersArray) {
                    NSString *counterName=counterElement.attributes[@"name"];
                    NSMutableArray *itemsArray=(NSMutableArray *)counterDict[counterName];
                    if (itemsArray == nil) {
                        itemsArray=[NSMutableArray new];
                        counterDict[counterName]=itemsArray;
                    }
                    NSArray *dishArray=[counterElement childrenWithTagName:@"dish"];
                    for (TFHppleElement *dishElement in dishArray) {
                        Item *newItem=[Item new];
                        TFHppleElement *dishNameElement=[dishElement firstChildWithTagName:@"name"];
                        NSString *text=[[dishNameElement firstTextChild].content stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""];
                        newItem.title=text;
                        TFHppleElement *dishUrlElement=[dishElement firstChildWithTagName:@"url"];
                        text=[[dishUrlElement firstTextChild].content stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""];
                        newItem.url=text;
                        [itemsArray addObject:newItem];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"Invalid day name %@",dayString);
        }
    }

}
```

The `init` method is -

```
-(id)init:(NSData *)menuData {
    if (self=[super init]) {
        [self populateMenuArray];
        [self parseXML:menuData];
    }

    return self;
}
```

where `menuData` is the NSData returned from your URL.  You would create the model using

```
 self.deliData=[[DeliData alloc]init:menuData];
```

The whole class is available here - https://gist.github.com/paulw11/da11ab3c7688c6deb1d7

Comment: check chat when u get a chance

Comment: check chat if you can

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
-(id)init:(NSData *)menuData {
if (self=[super init]) {
    [self populateMenuArray];
    [self parseXML:menuData];
}

return self;
```

}